# How do I get count of comments for one news?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a table in database : `TBL_New`s  and another one : `TBL_Comments`
Now I can show news and comments but I want to show counts of each news in one gridview.
I have a gridview on the page that shows last news (title of news) i want to show them like this :

```
grdNews.DataSource = 
    (from n in context.TBL_News
    join nc n context.TBL_Categories on p.CategoryID equals nc.CategoryID 
    select new {n.NewsID, n.NewsTitle,nc.CategoryTitle});

grdNews.DataBind();
```

My first news - Posted in : Sport News, By : Admin, Comments:25

That 25 is counts of this news.

How do I get counts of comments for each news?

Comment: is there is any relationship between TBL_News and TBL_Comments...

Comment: No i didnt set relationship in sql but absolutely TBL_News and TBL_Comments are in relation with NewsID

Answer (score 2):

I got it!

just use another select query in this query :

```
grdNews.DataSource = 
(from n in context.TBL_News 
join nc n context.TBL_Categories on p.CategoryID equals nc.CategoryID
 select new 
{n.NewsID,
 n.NewsTitle,
 nc.CategoryTitle,
 CommentsCount = 
 (from c in context.TBL_Comments where c.NewsID == n.NewsID select c).Count()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are related together by NewsID you can filter TBL_Comments upon loaded NEWS from TBL_News.
Its easier to have a DataModel and manage everything by say LINQ.

Comment: You need to join them together upon NewsID and then you can have all your comments for specific NewsID.
Then you can use COUNT(*) to get the numbers of columns.

Comment: Oh, sounds you have found the solution. Just saw your own answer.